# How to render front-end pages in Slim Framework route?

Tags: php, routes, slim

I have Slim installed in my folder, and I want to know if it's possible to render a full html/css/js page from a Slim route.

Suppose that this is the file that control the routes:

**rControl.php**

```
<?php
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

require '../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Slim\App;
$app->get('/myroute', function (Request $request, Response $response){

    /* I want to render the page when enter in this route*/ 

return $response;
});

$app->run();
```

and suppose that I have a custom html file with css formatting:

**myTemplate.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<title>My title </title>
</head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.min.css">

<script src="jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/engine.js"></script>

<body>

<h1> Some text </h1>

<p> example text here </p>

<div> hi! more content... </div>

</body>
</html>
```

The question is: **How can I show the content of *myTemplate.html* page when the user go to the route *"/myroute"*?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to use [PHP-View](https://github.com/slimphp/PHP-View).

```
<?php
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use Slim\Views\PhpRenderer;

require '../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Slim\App;
$container = $app->getContainer();
$container['renderer'] = new PhpRenderer("./templates");

$app->get('/myroute', function (Request $request, Response $response){
    return $this->renderer->render($response, "/myTemplate.html");
});

$app->run();
```

Traditionally, we use the `.phtml` extension for the templates to indicate that they can have PHP code in them. You can pass data to the template file via an array as the third parameter to `render()`.